# Angular - Set selected value in dropdown using patch

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm creating a "Edit View" for my application, I receive the information from an API call and then I use patch to set those values into my form. I'm facing some major issues on the dropdown select because the patch value doesn't seem to put the default value from the API. Whats is the correct way to bind data from my API into my select?

I searched for similar questions as mine and I found out that I need to set ngModel, I tried inside the option and select tags but it doesnt work either.

Select tag (HTML)

```html
<mat-grid-tile>
    <p class="input-ref mandatory">Industry Type</p>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline" [floatLabel]="'always'">
        <mat-label>Industry Type</mat-label>
        <mat-select placeholder="" formControlName="IndustryType2">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let industryType2 of industryTypes" [value]="industryType2">
{{ industryType2 }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Industry type options (this are always static)

```
industryTypes = [
        '(MH)',
        '(HS)',
        '(CM)',
        '(HL)',
        '(IS)'
    ];
```

I create my forms using FormBuild and then I populate the form with an API call

```
// CREATE FORMS
this.userDetailsForm = this.fb.group({
    IndustryType2: ['']
})

// POPULATE FORMS
this.initRequests().then((data) => {
    this.userDetailsForm.patchValue(data)
})
```

This is the JSON response I receive from my API

```
{
    IndustryType2: ["(MH)"],
    OtherProperty: ["Example"],
    ...
}
```

Comment: well first of all for each property the values are in an array, is it truly so?

Comment: @AJT_82 The values for the IndustryType2 come inside an array. Other values I don't think they matter because they work on my form I'm only facing the issue with dropdown selects.

Comment: well then that is the reason why it's not found. a string inside an array is not the same as a string.

Comment: Okey, but how could I set my value on my dropdown using the array?. I can't change my API. Any advice is helpful @AJT_82

Comment: well if there is one item in the array you need to do something like `this.userDetailsForm.get('industryType2').setValue(data.IndustryType2[0])` Also now noticed in template you are using `IndustryType`, but your form is built with `industryType`. Aren't you getting an error from that?

Comment: @AJT_82 It was a typo, tried your approach and it worked, thanks!!!. Another quick question so in order to make patch work for dropdown I need to use a string?. How come that base text input gets prefilled using an array?

Comment: Well in your select you are using strings, so it need to match. Since you were trying to match `(MH)` with `['(MH)']`. They are not the same, thus it cannot be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach in my project.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  IndustryType2: this.fb.group({
    id: ['']
  });
});

<mat-form-field class="full-width" formGroupName="IndustryType2"  appearance="outline" [floatLabel]="'always'">
  <mat-label>Industry Type</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="" formControlName="id">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let industryType2 of industryTypes" [value]="industryType2">
      {{ industryType2 }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

When you patch it will automatically patch your value

**solution 2:**

you can select the data or id to the by

```
form.get('controlname').setValue(res.id);
```

live example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditionaldropdown-gnajge)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
   this.initRequests().then((data) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(data);
        const patchValueData = {};
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
        patchValueData[key] = k[key][0]
        });
        this.userDetailsForm.patchValue(patchValueData)
    });
```